# bootstrap vue table field label value is not showing

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

bootstrap vue table field label value is not showing.

```
  fields: [
            { key: "selected", sortable: false, test: true },
            { key: 'id', label: "Number", sortable: true },
            { key: "employee",  label: "Driver", sortable: false },
            { key: "vehicle", sortable: false },
            { key: "type", sortable: false },
            { key: "city", sortable: false },
            { key: "total_bilties", sortable: false },
            { key: "quantity", sortable: false },
            { key: "fare", sortable: false },
            { key: "labour", sortable: false },
            { key: "adv", sortable: false },
            { key: this.$t("action"), sortable: false }
        ],
```

output
[image]

it's not showing the Number in ID & Driver in the employee column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as per the official documentation, I just created a sample demo for the reference. Please have a look and try to find the root cause of the issue.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      items: [
        { id: 1, employee: 'Alpha', vehicle: 'Vehicle A' },
        { id: 2, employee: 'Beta', vehicle: 'Vehicle B' },
        { id: 3, employee: 'Gamma', vehicle: 'Vehicle C' },
        { id: 4, employee: 'Omega', vehicle: 'Vehicle D' }
      ],
      fields: [
        { key: 'id', label: 'Number', sortable: true },
        { key: 'employee',  label: 'Driver', sortable: false },
        { key: 'vehicle', sortable: false }
      ]
    }
})
```

```html
<!-- Load Vue -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
  </b-table>
</div>
```